# ExtJs 4.2, grid relayEvents from store load event cause Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs, event-handling, grid

Here's the context, I've got a grid that can be dynamically reloaded by the user. As the content varies each times, I want to add in the grid's title the number of element present in the grid.

To do this, I wanted to relay the "load" event of the store behind this grid to the grid itself.

I thought I could use the Extjs relayEvents function as described [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-relayEvents)

here's my code:

```
initComponent : function(){
    var me = this;
    me.relayEvents(this.getStore(), ['load'], 'store');
    me.callParent();
},
```

As I am using a MVC architecture, the event is then handled in the grid's controller like so:

```
init : function() {
    this.control({
        'genericGrid' : {
            storeload: this.setTitle
        }
    });

},

setTitle : function(grid){

    var total=grid.getStore().count();
    grid.setTitle('List ('+total+')');

},
```

However, when I launch my application, all I get is blanck page and an error.

Under Chrome I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function            ext-all-dev.js:17772

and Firefox I get:

> TypeError: item.on is not a function ext-all-dev.js:17772

Exploring stackTrace on Chrome, i found that the error comes from the relayEvents method.

Can someone tell me what I did wrong, or maybe another way of doing this?

Comment: Does `this.getStore()` return an actual store object?

Comment: @And-y thanks for the tip.    this.getStore()  doesn't return the actual store but his name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your initComponet function exchange the order of `me.callParent` and `me.relayEvents`. After callParent the store should be created and getStore() should then return the store instance.

```
initComponent : function(){
  var me = this;
  me.callParent();
  me.relayEvents(this.getStore(), ['load'], 'store');
},
```